# VMWare Player vs VMWare Player Plus for running networking/database programs?

Tags: virtual, virtualbox, vmware, vmware-player

I'm new to VMWare and want to use VMWare to implement some networking examples(mainly just networking between two computers, and testing out some self-configuration and failsafe abilities). Also to possibly test out some failsafe capabilities of the Oracle Database.

I'm just not sure if I need to pay up $99 for the VMWare Player Plus , or am I Ok with just getting VirtualBox(free) or simple VMWare Player?

Overall I'm new to the Virtual-Machine arena, and I hope I can get some pointers on how to use these tools.

thank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with VMware Player. If it doesn't provide what you need you can look into a paid solution.

My guess based on the information you provided is that Player/VirtualBox will be sufficient for your needs.

One note on Player - you can launch multiple instances. It isn't terribly obvious and not laid out like Workstation/VirtualBox with an instance list/tree on the left.